# Encountering Certificate and Security Policy Issues When Writing Data from OPC UA Simulation Server to CnosDB via Telegraf

Tags: cnosdb

I am trying to write data from OPC UA Simulation Server to CnosDB via telegraf, but I am encountering the following problem:

```bash
2024-02-01T03:44:16Z W! [inputs.opcua] Failed to load certificate: open /etc/telegraf/cert.pem: no such file or directory
2024-02-01T03:44:16Z E! [inputs.opcua] Error in plugin: connect failed: error in Client Connection: opcua: invalid channel config: Security policy ' http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Aes128_Sha256_RsaOaep' requires a private key
2024-02-01T03:44:16Z E! [telegraf] Error running agent: input plugins recorded 1 errors
```

Here's a snippet of my config file.

```ini
[[inputs.opcua]]
  endpoint = "opc.tcp://IvandeMacBook-Pro.local:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer"
  name = "opcua"
```

What do I have to do to pass the validation?

Answer (score 0):

To skip authentication you need to set `security_policy` and `security_mode` to `None` as follows:

```
[[inputs.opcua]]
  endpoint = "opc.tcp://IvandeMacBook-Pro.local:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer"
  name = "opcua"
  security_policy = "None"
  security_mode = "None"
```